# How to speed up a CLOCK_MONOTONIC list of timestamps

Tags: python-3.x, math, time

I have a list of SECONDS.MICROSECONDS CLOCK_MONOTONIC timestamps like those below:

```
5795.944152
5795.952708
5795.952708
5795.960820
5795.960820
5795.969092
5795.969092
5795.977502
5795.977502
5795.986061
5795.986061
5795.994075
5795.994075
5796.002382
5796.002382
5796.010860
5796.010860
5796.019241
5796.019241
5796.027452
5796.027452
5796.035709
5796.035709
5796.044158
5796.044158
5796.052453
5796.052453
5796.060785
5796.060785
5796.069053
```

They each represent a particular action to be made.

What I need to do, in python preferably, but the programming language doesn't really matter, is to speed up the actions - something like being able to do a 2X, 3X, etc., speed increment on this list. So those values need to decrease in such a way to match the speed incrementation of ?X.

I thought of dividing each timestamp with the speed number I want, but it seems it doesn't work this way.

Comment: "but it seems it doesn't work this way." Please clarify in how far is it not working. Do you get an error? Does something unexpected happen? For that matter, how did you do it? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want to compute `T0 + (T - T0)/speedupfactor` for each time T, where T0 is the initial time (either a time you specify or the first time on the list or something).

Comment: @RobertDodier yes, this is exactly what needs to be done, it was as easy as `for x in timestamps:
    increasedtimestamp = float(t0) + (float(x) - float(t0))/speed
    speedtimestamps.append(round(Decimal(increasedtimestamp), 6))`. Thank you!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. You might be interested in a more "Pythonic" way, via list comprehension. Something like: `speedtimestamps = [(T0 + (T - T0)/speed for T in timestamps]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described and suggested by @RobertDodier I have managed to find a quick and simple solution to my issue:

```
speed = 2
speedtimestamps = [(t0 + (t - t0)/speed for t in timestamps]
```

Just make sure to remove the first line containing the first t0 timestamp.

Comment: How does that differ from what you had before? "I thought of dividing each timestamp with the speed number I want, but it seems it doesn't work this way."

Comment: I was dividing the whole timestamp not the difference between the timestamp and the initial T0 timestamp